# How to prevent java stream from running the same method twice?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Im trying to build a map of names to a values. I have this stream that is calling the method `getValue` twice. Once to make sure the return value isn't null and then again to actually collect the value. I'm trying to figure out how to add a lambda block to capture the return object.

```
Arrays.stream(enums)
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(
          en -> en.name(), 
          en -> ((issue.getValue(en) != null) ? issue.getValue(en) : "")
      ));
```

I keep getting various IDE syntax errors when I tried different arrangements. I feel like this should be trivial but yet it is eluding me. Any help would be awesome...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a block instead of a single expression:

```
theEnum -> { String v = issue.getValue(theEnum); return v != null ? v : ""; }
```

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick perfectly and was what I wanted to do to begin with. Note: that Yassin Hajaj's answer did also work but I gave this one the edge.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to use `Optional#ofNullable#orElse`

```
Arrays.stream(enums)
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
          en -> en.name(), 
          en -> Optional.ofNullable(issue.getValue(en)).orElse("")
       ));
```

Comment: Also, thanks for the answer. This did work in addition to weros answer. I went with theirs do to the fact that that it was more in line with what i was thinking. I'd mark both as right answers if i could but if i'm forced to split hairs, id pick theirs because I like it being in a lambda block for maintenance purposes and i feel as if it will be slightly faster.

Comment: @JustinA Hey Justin, as long as you've got what you wanted, it's ok to accept one or the other :).